# Black page or 404 every request in Asp.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core

my Asp.NET Core project returns 404 with Postman or a blank page with a browser after every request.
I'm using Asp.NET Core 1.1.2.
I already tried to:

- clean the solution
- delete the .vs folder
- restore Visual Studio
- create a new project and copy every file (empty project works)

Startup.cs, appsettings.json, web.config have not been edited.

I have SSL enabled and HTTPS rewrite.

This happenes on both IIS Express and the project directly.

Routing:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Log:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase:Debug: Request successfully matched the route with name 'default' and template '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}'.
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler:Debug: No actions matched the current request
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware:Debug: Request did not match any routes.

[image: Chrome]

[image: Postman]

Comment: How did you enable SSL, can you show your rewrite? Normally, this should work out of the box.

Comment: I think you need to follow exactly your home route to get something.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih I follow this link for SSL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl. However, SSL everything worked until this morning. Yesterday evening I restored Visual Studio because Xamarin went crazy. After the restore, this happened.

Comment: @Alexandru-DanPop It's the default routing rule and it worked since the start of the project.

Comment: Well this might be obvious but do you have a HomeController with the method Index? or which controllers/method combination are you trying to run?

Comment: I have multiple Controllers and APIs, none of them work anymore

Comment: Debug output: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 177.1313ms 302. Chrome:  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Log: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase:Debug: Request successfully matched the route with name 'default' and template '{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler:Debug: No actions matched the current request
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware:Debug: Request did not match any routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning. 
With version 1.1.x you need to add "app.UseApiVersioning()" in the configure method after app.UseMvc(...);